# datetime strptime converts 10 to 01?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am working with a date column in this form:

| Date |
| --- |
| 1871.01 |
| 1871.02 |
| ... |
| **1871.10** |
| 1871.11 |

So to convert the column to a datetimeindex, I use:
`df["Date"].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), "%Y.%m"))`
however the column is converted to:

| Date |
| --- |
| 1871-01-01 |
| 1871-02-01 |
| ... |
| **1871-01-01** |
| 1871-11-01 |

Does anyone have any idea of what causes this, where all "10"s convert to "01"s? Is there a better way to do this given my inputs are floats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first format is a float, the 1871.10 and 1871.1 are exactly the same numbers. So the string of it will have the second value (the shortest one). But then it would seems it is January (month 1).

So you should stringify forcing two digits:

```
df["Date"].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime("{:.2f}" % x, "%Y.%m"))
```

Note: the first format is very bad. The true solution is to correct it from beginning (e.g. when you read the input file you must tell the read function that the column is a date, not a float.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense thank you!

Comment: Actually, it pops the error "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting". 
Edit: despite the error, when displaying the data frame everything is formatted correctly!

Comment: One of your `x` is a tuple or list.

Comment: I don't think so... the entire column is floats of the form "yyyy.mm"?
And I tried this try:
try:
    df= pd.read_excel("data.xls", sheet_name="Data", header=7).iloc[0:-1]
    df['Date'] = df["Date"].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime("{:.2f}" % x, "%Y.%m"))
    pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%Y.%m")
except:
    pass

Due to a future warning to not parse directly in read_excel, but now it doesn't seem to do anything!

Comment: Even just "{:.2f}" % "1871.01" pops the same error, so maybe there is a problem with the f-string?

Comment: But so you have string and not float. Maybe you have a mix of float and string in the original column (string is a list of characters, so the error)

Comment: No I think the problem occurs when everything is converted to a string with datetime.strptime. After that all of the floats become strings and then the formatting/parser is applied.